# Output of LaTeX symbols using f-strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, latex, f-string

Please bear with me, as I don't quite understand the possible and impossible uses of f-strings.

Take the code:

```py
pi = 3.14159265
print(f'pi on 2 decimals is: {pi:.2f}')
```

Which obviously outputs: `pi on 2 decimals is: 3.14`

Would it be possible to have the following output:  `on 2 decimals is: 3.14`, with the usual pi symbol (instead of the 2 letters "pi"), using both `print` and f-string instructions?

Otherwise, what's stuck? Is it the use of f-string, or the use of `print`, or the mix of both?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass unicode like:

```
pi_value = 3.14159265
pi_unicode = "\u03C0"
print(f'{pi_unicode} on 2 decimals is: {pi_value:.2f}')
π on 2 decimals is: 3.14
```

The list of greek unicodes can be found [here](https://pythonforundergradengineers.com/unicode-characters-in-python.html)

[Note](https://python-3-for-scientists.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python3_features.html#unicode-variable-names), unicode variable names are also possible in Python 3:

> Python 3 allows many unicode symbols to be used in variable names. Unlike Julia or Swift, which allow any unicode symbol to represent a variable (including emoji) Python 3 restricts variable names to unicode characters that represent characters in written languages. In contrast, Python 2 could only use the basic ASCII character set for variable names.

```
π = 3.14
```

Answer (score 0):

Python doesn't understand LaTeX markup. But you can just write a literal π symbol in the source code:

```py
pi = 3.14159265
print(f'π on 2 decimals is: {pi:.2f}')
```

outputs

```
π on 2 decimals is: 3.14
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Zen of Python](https://peps.python.org/pep-0020/), there could be one way to do this. In this case, there are a few. And even if a language allows it, you need to carefully consider all the possible related problems a given solution can get you in.

## Unicode variable names

Python source code is interpreted as unicode. So this code works:

```
import math

π = math.pi
print(f"{π=:.2f}") # outputs π=3.14
```

## Escape sequence \N

According to Python documentation [on string literals](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals) you can use the `\N` symbol which means "character name in unicode database".

This way you can do something like this:

```
import math

print(f"\N{GREEK SMALL LETTER PI} on 2 decimals is: {math.pi:.2f}")
```

The full list of unicode characters with names is available here: https://www.unicode.org/Public/9.0.0/ucd/UnicodeData.txt . I assume it could be more readable in some cases.

Unicode sequences are a variation of it - as per [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63875029/401516)